# x86 Intel Assembly Linux sys_write + sys_read

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

The following code:

```
section        .bss

name:    resb 50

section        .text
global         _start

_start:
        PUSH   EBP
        MOV    EBP, ESP
        MOV    EDX, len
        MOV    ECX, msg
        MOV    EBX, 1
        MOV    EAX, 4
        INT    0x80
        MOV    EDX, 50
        MOV    ECX, name
        MOV    EBX, 0
        MOV    EAX, 3
        INT    0x80
        MOV    EBX, 1
        MOV    EAX, 4
        INT    0x80
        MOV    EDX, cm
        MOV    ECX, ex
        MOV    EBX, 1
        MOV    EAX, 4
        INT    0x80
        MOV    EBX, 0
        MOV    EAX, 1
        INT    0x80
section        .data

msg           db 'Hello!',0xa
ex            db '!',0xa
len           equ $ - msg
cm            equ $ - ex
```

I intended to make a simple I/O program that printed `Hello!`, asked for a char and would print `%c!`.

Input being `|` and output being `:`, I get the following:

```
:Hello!

:!

|4

:4

:!
```

How do I make it so that it returns the following

```
:Hello!

|4

:4!
```

Comment: I've not written any assembly in years, but those `equ`s at the end look like they're meant to be measuring strings - so the `len` one should come immediately after `msg`.

Comment: Please can you add comments to your code?  Even just a comment for each syscall would make this much easier to read.

Comment: Are you calling the read() syscall to read the text?  That would return "4\n", not just "4".  I think you're then printing that out without removing the "\n", which is why there's a newline between the "4" and "!".  But I'm making wild guesses about what your code does :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Damien_The_Unbeliever says, your `equ`s want to come immediately after the string they're supposed to measure. After your `sys_read`, `eax` will be the number of characters read, including the linefeed that ends the reading. You probably don't want to print the linefeed (in this case - sometimes you would). So:

```
mov edx, eax
dec edx
```

Or if you want to do it in one instruction:

```
lea edx, [eax - 1]
```

As it stands, `edx` still holds 50, so your next `sys_write` will print 50 characters. It will NOT stop at a zero or any other string-terminator. `ecx` will still contain `name`, but I would reload it just for clarity.

By rights, you should check for an error return (`eax` would be negative) after each and every `int 0x80` but an error is unlikely here.